# How can I chage the color of the link in Html.Action link, when the mouse is over the div?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I am using MVC3.
I have a table and an Html.ActionLink inside of it.
I have already set the text decoration for none, but the link is still blue. I change the table:hover background-color and the color(of the text), and when I put the mouse over the row, the text that are not a link gets white, but the link still blue. If I change the a:hover, the link gets white just when I put the mouse over it, and not just over the row.

Is there a way to do that with css?

Comment: Use Jquery. When the mouse hovers over the div get all the links in the div and change their color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, to cover all the anchors when you are hovering over the row.

```css
#tableid tr:hover a {
    /* Your Styles */
}
```

But this does not work on all IE browser so, use JS to catch the event and apply styles to anchors in it.

Comment: i would not any longer support IE < version 7 and in addition, i would not at all support a browser that does not support css2...
[whencaniusehover](http://caniuse.com/#search=:hover) if it is not prescribed

Comment: @r3bel, Yes, using scripting is the overall best solution.

Answer (score 1):

use the following css:

```
#yourTableId:hover a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

you can replace `#yourTableId` also with table and / or `.yourTablesClass` depending on where the css should be used ;)

this works also for child elements e.g.:

```
#yourTableId div:hover a

#yourTableId tr:hover a
```

so in general we can say you can use the following:

```
#yourTableId *:hover a
```

where * is a tagname, classname or id (dont forget class and id prefixes -> .classname and #idname)

[here a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nXSYX/1/)

Comment: Might be worth noting that this works for lower level elements than a table.. so that you can only highlight the anchors on the row.. perhaps: #yourTableId tr:hover a